# Display different contents in a given component Angular

Tags: angularjs, components, navbar, display

Thanks in advance for your help. I'm new to AngularJs and I'm trying to build a single page website. My goal is to have a sidebar(menu) on the left and a page content on the right. Whenever I click on a given button into this sidebar, I would like to see the corresponding content on the page content.

```
 +-------------------------------------------------+
 |                     Navbar                      |
 +------------+------------------------------------+
 |  Sidebar   |                                    |
 |            |                                    |
 |   Menu 1   |   Content                          |
 |   Menu 2   |     => Display 1 if menu1 clicked  |
 |   Menu 3   |     => Display 2 if menu2 clicked  |
 |            |     => Display 3 if menu3 clicked  |
 |            |                                    |
 |            |                                    |
 |            |                                    |
 +------------+------------------------------------+
```

I already implemented several components such as navbar, sidebar, user (to implement permissions etc) and pagecontent (which is a basically a white container) but I can't figure out how to proceed? Should I create one component for each button in the sidebar ? Can I choose which component to display in an already existing component (here, pagecontent) and how?

Comment: Read routing in angularjs

Comment: Just read and follow the steps: https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will read carefully.

Comment: I've read the tutorial but it seems to be an old version of angular...